# Specify n to use for percent computation in pipe/ggplot/facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage, facet-grid

I have a df that looks like this

```
df  <- structure(list(Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
                                                                                                "Male"), class = "factor"), Victim = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L
                                                                                                ), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), Crime = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                   2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                   1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                   3L, 1L), .Label = c("Kidnapping", "Robbery", "Sexual assault"
                                                                                                                                                                   ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -35L))
```

And I plotted it like this

```
df %>%
  group_by(Sex, Victim) %>% 
  count(Crime) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Victim, y=Percent))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_grid(Crime~Sex)
```

As one can see, percents were computed based on grouped data, so that each combination of Sex and Victim add up to 100%.

This is NOT what I want, however. What I would like to compute/plot is, for example, the percent of women who were not victims of kidnapping (57.14%, and not 50.00% as computed) in comparison with the women who were victims of kidnapping (42.85% , which is correct by accident).

How do I code this?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>%
  count(Sex, Crime, Victim) %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Crime) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>% .....` ?

Comment: @Axeman it works, many thanks!